# Using scipy.optimize.brute: How I get the minimizer outside the specified range?

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I just want to try with scipy.optimize.brute for a simplest function minimization case one might imagine: finding the minimum of the identity function `lambda x.x` in the grid `[1,2,3,...100]`.  Following the [documentation of scipy.optimize.brute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html), I use

```
scipy.optimize.brute(lambda x:x, (slice(1,100,1),))
```

The expected answer is, of course, `1`, but my python console gives me `-6.33825300e+28`. Why is it so far from the expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `finish=None`:

```
scipy.optimize.brute(lambda x:x, (slice(1,100,1),), finish=None)
```

The default behavior is to pass the output through `fmin` to improve it. The `ranges` aren't passed to `fmin`; they seem to be considered hints, rather than bounds. Specifying `finish=None` makes `brute` give you the brute-force solution directly.

If you *want* `fmin` to improve your results, work the bounds into your function:

```
scipy.optimize.brute(lambda x: (x if 1 <= x <= 100 else np.inf), (slice(1,100,1),))
```

Comment: I accept your answer although the workaround seems somewhat clumsy to me. By the way, your "lambda x: (x if 1 <= x <= 100 else np.inf"  becomes no more smooth. Do you think the default fmin still works well on such functions in general?

Comment: @zell: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, and unfortunately, the site I used to use to test SciPy stuff doesn't seem to be working. Can you explain what you mean by "becomes no more smooth"?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness. Your function lambda x: (x if 1 <= x <= 100 else np.inf) is not continuous, which may break some assumption that your local minimizer rely on. I guess some local minimizer works well only if its objective function is 'well-behaved'. For instance, the category of convex optimization tools require, naturally,  the objective functions be convex. I was just unsure that fmin works well for the noncontinuous function that you just constructed:  lambda x: (x if 1 <= x <= 100 else np.inf).

Comment: @zell: `fmin` is this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html I don't think the sudden jump should throw it off.

Comment: @2357112 Thank you. By the way, what is "the site you used to use to test SciPy stuff"? Do you mean we can test scipy from an web interface?

Comment: @zell: I use this: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/ It doesn't seem to be loading properly for me, but when it does, it's an IPython environment with a bunch of useful packages installed.